# How to Change Font Size System Wide on OS X 10.11 El Capitan (MacBook Retina)

Tags: osx-el-capitan, macbook-pro-retina

On the MacBook Retina with OS X 10.11 El Capitan:

**How can you change the font size system wide with built-in functionality?**

Comment: Changing the font size alone is not possible - it would break all kinds of GUI elements. Instead you change the system zoom, as Moe Pad explains below.

Comment: & I only just realised Q & A are the same person >.<

Comment: Yes, it was both me ^^  I still would up vote your comment, but I cannot yet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a solution to change only the font size, but this is the closest you get with built-in functionality:

Go to *System settings -> Display -> Scaled* and select *larger text*. It also adjust other stuff as well, so the over all experience is even better.

That's it :)

For more information see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471

Comment: It would be worth mentioning that this only applies to users of Retina displays to avoid them searching through menus with frustration wondering why this option is missing. While the OP does, I would imagine that few El Capitan users overall have Retina displays. I wonder if there are any third party solutions to this problem ?